Apt can't find debian backports firmware
I'm trying to use Debian Bookworm backports to update my amdgpu firmware.
I added this to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports per the instructions, and tacked on non-free per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467108/50441 and also non-free-firmware
~$cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-backports main contrib non-free-firmware non-free

I am able to update the kernel fine:
~$apt policy linux-image-amd64
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: 6.6.13-1~bpo12+1
  Candidate: 6.6.13-1~bpo12+1
  Version table:
 *** 6.6.13-1~bpo12+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.1.85-1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
     6.1.76-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
     6.1.67-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages

However, the backport version firmware does not show up in apt.
~$sudo apt-get install firmware-amd-graphics/bookworm-backports
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package firmware-amd-graphics is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Release 'bookworm-backports' for 'firmware-amd-graphics' was not found

I was able to find it at https://packages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/firmware-amd-graphics and download it manually, but this is very weird.
~$apt policy  firmware-amd-graphics
firmware-amd-graphics:
  Installed: 20230210-5~bpo11+1
  Candidate: 20230210-5
  Version table:
     20230210-5 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free-firmware i386 Packages
 *** 20230210-5~bpo11+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


There is no bookworm-backports version of the firmware-amd-graphics package, that’s why apt can’t find it.
The version you found is from bullseye-backports, and is the same as the version in Debian 12. In fact, the package version is older than the version in Debian 12; the next time you run apt upgrade the package will be “upgraded” to the Debian 12 version.

Thanks, figured it was probably me being dumb.

Nothing dumb about it, you’re not the first to be confused by the various backports suites. The lack of updates to the firmware package can be surprising too (it’s rather difficult to deal with so doesn’t get updated often during a release’s development).
